# How to assign an account id to page visits with GA API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I have created a website that allows users to create content that is available to the public. Each page of content has a unique url.

A user is part of an account, and I want to be able to show GA data for all the content pages of a specific account.

What I am looking to do, is to use the GA API to assign the account ID to the page view, and then to filter the page views per account.

I also want to be able to see the total page views for all the accounts, for the backend of our system.

I have never used the GA API before, and not sure if this is possible, I was hoping someone who is familiar with the API, could point me in the right direction. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics API isn't appropriate to create this data.

Instead, you will want to make the users accountID available when the page view tag is fired, and capture the value as a custom dimension.

Through creating a custom report, with the custom dimension "Account ID" you could then select the metrics you are interested in, e.g. pageviews, session duration, etc.